# Tenda N4 Wi-Fi router not authenticating

Tags: windows, networking, router, wireless-router, android

Okay, so I have [Tenda N4](http://www.tenda.cn/uk/product/N4.html) router configured with WPA-PSK,AES with DHCP. It used to work fine with these same settings. But now, whenever I am providing password, it shows “Authentication problem,” in Android and Windows 7 says “password mismatch” or simply won’t connect to it.

I know the Wi-Fi router is working fine, since I have another older Wi-Fi router as well (which used to work fine but had only “g,” so got a “N” type), it shows the same error with that router as well.

The weird thing is, if I pull out the LAN cable from router and giving password, it is getting connected immediately to router but—of course—there will be no Internet.

I have checked these things:

1. Drivers are updated in both Android and Windows.
2. Disabled the Lan connection in Windows 7, keeping the Wi-Fi ON only.
3. Tried WEP and no encryption: It connects with WEP but the speed is very slow, around 3 kbps!
4. Made sure that nothing is near the router and have placed devices very close to it as well.
5. Internet works fine, if I am using the cable instead of Wi-Fi.
6. Went to Wi-Fi profiles in both windows and android and have deleted them.

I am at a loss to understand whats going on, how can I use Wi-Fi if they made to work without lan-cables in them?

Comment: Try WPA2-PSK only (WPA2 only, AES-CCMP only). Make sure original WPA and TKIP are not enabled in any way. Also make sure your password only uses printable 7-bit ASCII characters.

Comment: Thank you@Spiff for the fast reply, I am going to try these settings and post the results.

Comment: Also, if you have any other routers that could possibly be configured with the same SSID, power them down.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, I have made sure that no other routers are on with same SSID's, thank you, David.

Comment: @Spiff, Changes made- default was: WPA-PSK, changed to: WPA2 and PSK. Made sure TKIP is not enabled anywhere. Default wifi password- 12345678
changed to: abcdefgh. Outcome: 1)Windows 7 was able to connect but the speed is again 3kbps, disconnected and tried to reconnect got error that "Windows was unable to connect to Tenda_2D34xx"
android was able to connect at very less speed, disconnected and tried to reconnect it kept asking for password again.

Answer (score -1):

```
Thanks Spiff and David.
```

Ok, so I have fixed my issue. I am explaining the solution here for anyone who might face the same problem in future:
Change connection type to static in router, enter the numbers. Make it DHCP in mobile and remove static ip configurations from laptop. Turn everything off for one minute and connect. Also, try inserting the lan cable in WAN port.
Only drawback with this is that, earlier, I had different static IPs for mobile and laptop so that if I am downloading something in laptop it wont affect mobile's speed. Now everything connects to one IP in router.

Comment: This solution makes no sense. What exactly did the problem turn out to be? It sounds like you just fiddled with a bunch of stuff and it suddenly started working, but you didn't explicitly identify and fix the root cause.

Comment: I agree, let me rephrase. Earlier I had LAN wire in LAN port with dynamic setting in router and multiple static IPs in devices, It used to work. Now I am putting the LAN wire in WAN port and it somehow connects the devices to the same IP/Connection. So, since router is already setting a IP (in WAN) and if I am still using the static IP on devices, they were conflicting with the IP set in the router and hence, all the issues with the speed and disconnections.